# Cannot import modules even though the are in the same directory as the file I am working in

Tags: python

I cannot import modules even though they are in the same directory I am working in right now (E:\Python Projekti\Python Crash Course). I tried to find the solution here and I thought I found it with .module_name , but it still does not work.

I tried the .module_name method, and it gives me the drop-down menu with all possible modules, but in the end, it gives me an error in the terminal.

```
from .restaurant_module import Restaurant

restaurant = Restaurant('Madera', 'Soulfood')
restaurant.describe_restaurant()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Python Projekti/Python Crash Course/Chapter 
9/imported_restaurant.py", line 1, in <module>
from .restaurant_module import Restaurant
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.restaurant_module'; 
'__main__' is not a package
```

Comment: Does it work with just `import restaurant_module`?

Comment: Use `from restaurant_module import Restaurant` instead. Do not use relative import (with a `.`) unless the module is not at the top-level project directory.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It gives me an error 'No module named restaurant_module'. I forgot to mention this started happening since I upgraded to the newest 19.2 version of Pycharm. I also did not have python in my path (after updating Pycharm), but I solved that.

Comment: @blhsing I tried that as well, doesn't work. Here is the path where my current file is located, as well as all the modules I want to use (E:\Python Projekti\Python Crash Course\Chapter 9)

Comment: Your file is in that directory, but the _current working directory_ may be something else.  Try adding this to the top of your code: `import os; print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: In PyCharm, right click on the `Chapter 9` folder, click on "Mark Directory as", and then click on "sources root". Then `from restaurant_module import Restaurant` will work.

Comment: @blhsing It worked, thank you a lot. To be sure, do I have to change the sources root every time I change the directory now?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes you do have to change the sources root every time you want to run your script from a different "Chapter" folder. But normally you should really create a separate project for each chapter to begin with, so that you don't have keep setting a different sources root just to run a script from a different sub-folder.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try what Jammy suggested: `import restaurant_module` or try adding a blank file in the same directory named `__init__.py` and seeing if that works.

Edit: does this repo help you structure it? https://github.com/ehmatthes/pcc